# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Server PHPMyAdmin client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

First of all, I searched now nearly an hour through the Questions and didn't find any matching ones. So, if I have overseen something, be patient with me.

I'm hosting a VServer on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with a MySQL-Database on Apache 2.4.7. Everything runs fine with that. Now I want to install PHPMyAdmin to get easier access to the database.

Since I'm not that firm with Ubuntu Server I checked the tutorial on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

After I ran through the installation and reconfiguring process I reloaded (and restarted) my apache2, but I still get a 403 with the message `You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.` when I try to get to `http://myserverip/phpmyadmin`.

With the restart of my apache2 this message occured:`[alias:warn] [pid 29422] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.`

In my apache error.log I found this entry saying not much to me: `AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Not that this solves your problem, but it's weird that that article tells you to add the Apache conf file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf. IMO all Apache conf files should be within /etc/apache2/sites-available/ (and symlinked to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/) for simplicity.

Comment: What's there in the line at `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3`?

Comment: Your IP address is included in the "Allow from ...." line?

Comment: zxcmehran: Line 3: `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

Comment: szpal: Where is the "Allow from .. " line?

Comment: Okay, I added a line Allow from all in <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin> ... now the phpmyadmin-Page and Login is available. But there are no databases listed ..

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm going to answer my own question.
I added the Allow from line to my PHPMyadmim Config file. After that I granted all Privileges to my PHPMyAdmin user and tadaaaa, here wie go. Pretty simple thow there is still the warning when I restart my Apache2.. Anyone any idea?